# Java Soap Glassfish get session after Login

Tags: java, session, authentication, soap, glassfish

I have web method **Login**:

```
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @Override
    public String LogIn(String UserName, String Password, String PhoneNumber) {
            String username = "";
            String password = "";
        if (UserName != null) {
            username = UserName;
        }
        if (Password != null) {
            password = Password;
        }
        System.out.println("username is"+username);
        System.out.println("password is"+password);

        if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
            String session = session_id.AddObject(PhoneNumber);
            return session;

        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I'm find, that set Session may be, extends class of httpServlet, like this:

```
 @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  


            HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);  
            session.setAttribute("doneSessed", nameInput);  
            //HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
    }
```

After set Session clients, i'm want save input parameter to compare this parameter with session_id(i'm want use for this SqLite).

Question, how can i set session, after success Login?

Comment: How do you call `LogIn`? What is `session_id`?

Comment: I'm call WebMethod LogIn from my Android client. It's worked, i'm testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add :

```
   @Resource
    WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    public String LogIn(String UserName, String Password, String PhoneNumber) {
     ...
        MessageContext mc = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpSession session =    ((javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
        if (session == null)
             throw new WebServiceException("No Session found");
     ...
```